# Check if mongodb document has a property that isn't defined in schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am finding a document with mongoose using `findOne`. I succeded in setting a property, that is not defined in the schema, to the document using `doc.set(key, val)`. However when I want to check if the document has that property or not, it just shows no even if the document has it.

```
User.findOne({email: req.user.email})
    .then(user=>{
        if(user.posts){
            //Tried with user.has("posts")=>logs error: .has is not a function
            let posts = user.get("posts");
            posts.push({
                    "Type": "Idea",
                    "Field/s of idea": req.body["Field/s of idea"],
                    "Idea": req.body.idea,
                    "Date": new Date()
                    });
            user.set("posts", posts);
        }else{
            user.set("posts", [{
                    "Type": "Idea",
                    "Field/s of idea": req.body["Field/s of idea"],
                    "Idea": req.body.idea,
                    "Date": new Date()
                    }]
            );
        };
        user.save();
    })
    .catch(err=>{throw err});
```

Schema code:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: ObjectId, auto: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true, max:18},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true, min:5},
    date_of_registration: {type: Date, required: true}
}, { strict: false });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schemas are fixed and not dynamic by design.  If you are unsure about what type `posts` will be, add it to your schema and use the `Mixed` type.

Something like

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    posts: [ { type: Mixed, required: false } ]
}, { strict: false });
```

Comment: In fact, I am unsure if there will be a `posts`. `posts` will be added only if the user decide to add something. I he doesn't add something, then there won't be `posts`.

Comment: @EyePatch You can still add `posts` to your schema and set the type to `Mixed`.  It doesn't have to be a required field.  In this case, only documents with `posts` will show the field populated.

Comment: So you cannot add a field to a document unless it is in the schema?

Comment: Mongoose enforces the schema that you design. This is to ensure that values not specified do not get stored to the database. If you want to add fields dynamically, you can disable the `strict` option with something like `var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });`.  But you shouldn't do this unless you have a good reason to.  You can read more about it here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Comment: I think i forgot to include the schema. It  already have the strict option disabled

Comment: Can you include your schema in your question?

Comment: Does the problem come from the schema??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194451/discussion-between-developing2020-and-eye-patch).